# FileReader API working in jsFiddle, but not from local file

Tags: html, google-chrome, fileapi

I'm working on a Chrome/Firefox extension which will be using the file API to store files locally. I'm trying to get an example up and running but I'm running into issues which seem to center around Chrome. Can anyone explain why [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danwoods/3jNyx/) works fine, but the [exact same code](http://pastebin.com/6QjiewZn), when run from a local file, doesn't work. Please note that it works fine in Firefox, just not in Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has unusually restrictive web security; many things, like Ajax, won't work when run locally. This is one of them. You can get around this problem by either using a local websever, like @ephemient suggests, or you can run Chrome in unsafe mode for testing:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: See also --allow-file-access-from files http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/11/29/disabling-cross-domain-security-check-for-ajax-development-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Or you could make a packaged app....  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html

Comment: @PAEz: I was suggesting this as a temporary solution for testing, otherwise things could get inconvenient. Definitely not a final solution (what with the "disabling security" and all) `:)`

Comment: @minitech And a good suggestion it is aslong as your aware and cautious...I also was just offering another suggestion ;).  One thing tho, if your going to use that it might be good to also use `-user-data-dir` and point it to some directory just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  Chrome's [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents just about everything in `file://` from working[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787).  Use a local webserver instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome. Start the chrome from command line with the flag
 --allow-file-access-from-files
chrome doesn't support for accessing local file without this flag.