# Why is this code not alerting the text in the text file? (javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, file, file-io

Here is my code. The problem is that the information isn't being alerted. It worked in Js Fiddle but not on chrome/firefox/safari. When I tried to use document.write to display the text in JsFiddle that didn't work either. This code is giving me lots of problems.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
            //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
            var files = evt.target.files;
            if (files) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    r.onload = (function(f) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var contents = e.target.result;
                            alert(contents);
                        };
                    })(f);
                    r.readAsText(f);;
                }
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load files");
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileinput"/>

​</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are assigning the event to an element that doesn't exist yet. You could move the code to the bottom of the page, or use a DOMready event  (Google's API may expose one, I don't know)

Comment: EDIT: Disregard this. possible duplicate of [FileReader API working in jsFiddle, but not from local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745568/filereader-api-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-from-local-file)

Comment: this might be the problem `r.readAsText(f);;`

Comment: That didn't fix it. Is there a way to bypass chrome's security if that's the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
}
```

Instead of just

```
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
```

Edit: So yeah, the solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745568/filereader-api-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-from-local-file)

execute chrome with `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` for windows or `google-chrome --disable-web-security` for linux.

Comment: Or do what Pekka said and move the entire `<script>` block and paste it after your `<input>` element.

Comment: neither seems to have worked. Chrome has weird security settings, but if it works in JSFiddle shouldn't it work in chrome.

Comment: Jsfiddle runs the code you write in the Javascript section inside a `window.onload` by default.